# Angular JS - Filter and Group

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a collection of data I am getting back from my database as JSON. I need to filter through these results and get the name of each sales rep I am getting back. The trick is that each sales rep is in my results more than once but in my final list I only want the name to be included once.

So something like Sarah, Ben, Ben, John, Mike, Luke, John

Would return Sarah, Ben, John, Mike, Luke

```
    $http({
        url: '/Clients/Orders/Json',
        method: "GET",
        params: {}
    }).success(function (data) {
        var JSON = data;
        $scope.data = JSON; 
    });
```

My data is found in the $scope.data.

I am looking for ideas on building a filter to run this data through and then how to access that filtered information on my view page.

Answer (score 0):

Filter -

```
app.filter('distinct', function() {
    return function(arrayInput) {
        var distinctArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayInput.length; i++) {
            if( distinctArray.indexOf(arrayInput[i]) < 0 ){
                distinctArray.push(arrayInput[i]);
            }
        }

        return distinctArray;
    };
});
```

And then inject your filter `distinctFilter` in controller or service to filter out distinct names from the array `$scope.data`

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, distinctFilter) {
    ...
    // populate $scope.data with array of names

    $scope.distinctNames = distinctFilter($scope.data);

});
```